# Wordpress wp-admin redirect loop

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, authentication

I know this question is asked many times here. But none of the answers solved my problem.

When I try to log-in to my site through wordpress-admin, like this, mysite.com/wp-admin it gives me the error "This webpage has a redirect loop". But when I try mysite.com/wp-admin/index.php, It works fine.

1. one conclusion I came to, is, there is no problem with plugins. I tried changing the plugins directory name. It doesn't work.
2. I tried changing file permissions. It doesn't work.
3. Added the following code to .htaccess file

   ```
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule  /wp-admin/ /wp-admin/index\.php [L,P]
   ```

It too doesn't work for me.

Please help me. What else can I do? Can anyone give me suggestions?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG  add code see whats the issue there.

Comment: Change the theme to TwentyTwelve, does it still happen? Is there any `mu-plugins` in wp-content folder?

Comment: @brasofilo , even When I disable all the plugins, the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

insert this code in your functions.php file

```
 function admin_default_page() {
 return 'http://staging.bestbodybootcamp.com/wp-admin/index.php';
 }

 add_filter('login_redirect', 'admin_default_page');
```

Answer (score 0):

you have not specify what is your permalink setting is 'Post name' or default, if it is default or any else please change to post name

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But permalinks is in 'Post name' mode only.

Comment: Hay bro can you please try this
http://staging.bestbodybootcamp.com/wp-login.php
Please clear cache and as cookie

Comment: When i login like that, the logs in. But not redirected to dashboard. again I get the same redirect loop error. I have to use another admin url like staging.bestbodybootcamp.com/wp-admin/edit.php to see the dash board. 

also I am working in a company and it is the task given to me. I cannot tell them to use that url. I was asked to make the task done.

Comment: Can you give the user name and password of admin for further testing if you want, you can believe me.

Comment: Is there any facility here to message personally?

Comment: It says Call to undefined function add_filter()

Comment: What you saying you put all code, because i m trying in my local and it's work fine

Comment: I just copied all the code and pasted in wp-includes/functions.php

It says, Call to undefined function add_filter().. anything wrong with me??

Comment: No, not in wp-include/ you have to put  wp-content/ in functions.php file at the bottom of file

Comment: I put in wp-content/themes/bbbc/functions.php. It doesn't work

Comment: did you add the code to functions.php in my site ? and is it working??

Comment: Can you please tell me where exactly I need to add the code??

in wp-content/themes/bbbc/functions.php?? or somewhere else??

Comment: i think something wrong in put your code,because i m not see this code appearance menu in editor submenu  in functions.php file,if you change this file permission to 777 so im edit this code via cms